# PDCurses wont compile on windows

Tags: c, windows, gcc, pdcurses

I am trying to compile PDCurses, but when it attempts to compile pdcscrn.c  it gives the error message

```
../wincon/pdcscrn.c:93:5: error: unknown type name 'PCONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFOEX'; did you mean 'PCONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO'?
     PCONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFOEX lpConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx);
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     PCONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO
../wincon/pdcscrn.c:95:5: error: unknown type name 'PCONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFOEX'; did you mean 'PCONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO'?
     PCONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFOEX lpConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx);
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     PCONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO
../wincon/pdcscrn.c:97:8: error: unknown type name 'SetConsoleScreenBufferInfoExFn'
 static SetConsoleScreenBufferInfoExFn pSetConsoleScreenBufferInfoEx = NULL;
```

and there are also a lot more lines, but that is the first part. I am using GCC 8.2.0, and I compiling the wincon directory because I am on windows 10. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is addressed in wincon/README.md:

- If your build stops with errors about PCONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFOEX,
  add the parameter "INFOEX=N" to your make command line and try again.
  (This will happen with older compile environments.)

BTW, you should specify the exact toolset you're using, since AFAIK there's no such thing as raw GCC for Windows -- it'll be something like MinGW or Cygwin.